# High number of requests turning into 4xx due to unsupported HTTP method OPTIONS

Tags: rest, http, amp-html, http-options-method

Some of our APIs(REST) getting a high number of requests with HTTP method OPTIONS. While these APIs only supports GET method. Since OPTIONS is not supported, All these requests turn into 4xx.

Observations: These requests coming

- From different client IPs
- With blank referer
- With valid user-agent. I checked randomly, request are from mobile browsers.

What do I do with these requests? 
How do I ensure that these requests are valid?
Should I enable OPTIONS along with GET?

**Please note** that some of the pages have an AMP version of it. Could this be related?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

Many frontends (frameworks like Angular) send so called "preflight requests".

> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the
>   CORS protocol is understood.
>
> It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers:
>   Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the
>   Origin header.
>
> A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser, when needed.
>   In normal cases, front-end developers don't need to craft such
>   requests themselves.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

So if it's legit for your API to have different frontends using it, I'd say you should accept these headers.

Comment: In our case, I don't think there is a need of prefight request as there is no chance of cross-domain request. The only possible case could be AMP